# Changing a static 2D array into a Dynamic array in a class C++

Tags: c++, arrays, multidimensional-array, dynamic-arrays

I have a 2D char array filled with '_' 's, I have made a static array and I wanted to change it to dynamic so you can change the size of the board, do I need to assign a pointer in public and int's in private? Or will I have to make a new array completely? Thanks :)

```
#include "stdafx.h"
#include <iostream>
#include <string>
#include <sstream>


using namespace std;

class board
{

public:
    void makeBoard()
    {
        for (int i = 0; i < 11; yaxis++)
        {
            for (int j = 0; j < 11; xaxis++)
            {
                opening[i][j] = '_';
            }
        }
    }

private:
    char placement[11][11];
};
```

Comment: Why wont you use something more 'C++' ? `std::array`, `std::vector`,...

Comment: Whenever you think "dynamic array", your next thought should be [*`std::vector`*](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/container/vector).

Comment: @FilipKočica I'm quite new to C++, first time trying to make an array like this!

Comment: @Someprogrammerdude okay no worries thanks alot :)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As suggested, `std::vector` is probably the way to go. Here is a small example that might help you:

```
#include <vector>

class board
{

public:
    board(int x, int y)
    {
        resize(x, y);
    }

    void resize(int x, int y) 
    {
        // make sure input is OK
        mBoard.clear();
        for (int i = 0; i < x; ++i) 
            mBoard.emplace_back(std::vector<char>(y, '_'));
    }
private:
    std::vector<std::vector<char>> mBoard; // 2 dimensional std::vector
};
```

And create by

```
board my_board(11, 11);
my_board.resize(2, 10); // Resize afterwards
```